# Sql query select by parent id

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I need select data from table like this (its just example).

I want select data in format like Category1,Category2,Category3 without root by parent_id

| id_category | name | parent_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | root | 1 |
| 2 | Graphic card | 1 |
| 3 | Memory | 1 |
| 4 | DDR3 | 3 |
| 5 | Corsair | 4 |
| 6 | HyperX | 4 |

The result should be

| category1 | category2 | category3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| GraphicCard | null | null |
| Memory | DDR3 | Corsair |
| Memory | DDR3 | HyperX |

Comment: You can use CTE (Common Table Expressions) for MySQL: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html look at Hierarchical Data Traversal, if you need further help with your SELECT leave a comment and I will help you here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour could be achieved using self joins.
This should do the trick:

```
select a.name as category1, b.name as category2, c.name as category3 
from yourtable a
left join yourtable b on a.id_category = b.parent_id
left join yourtable c on b.id_category = c.parent_id
where a.id_category in (2,3);
```